# TypeScript: 'unknown[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'R', but 'R' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'unknown[]

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a simple executor which runs thunks one by one and returns thunks' results in an array:

```js
type Thunk<R> = () => R;

type MapToThunk<T extends [...unknown[]]> = T extends  [infer Head, ...infer Tail] ? [Thunk<Head>, ...MapToThunk<Tail>] : [];

function executeSequentially<R extends [...unknown[]]>(thunks: MapToThunk<[...R]>): R {
  let result = [];
  for (const thunk of thunks) {
    result.push(thunk());
  }
  return result;
}
```

But tsc gives me "Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'R'.
'unknown[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'R', but 'R' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'unknown[]'."

Why does the type-checking fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should type your function in different way.
As far as I understand, you should return an array of function results (of return types)

Hence, it is better to infer each element in `thunks` and compute its return type.

Consider this example:

```js
type Fn = () => any
const execute = <Thunk extends Fn, Thunks extends Thunk[]>(thunks: [...Thunks]) =>
  thunks.map<ReturnType<[...Thunks][number]>>((thunk) => thunk())

const result = execute([() => 42, () => 'string']) // (string | number)[]
```

If you want to infer a tuple instead of array, you can use this example:

```js
type Mapped<
  Arr extends Array<unknown>,
  Result extends Array<unknown> = []
  > = Arr extends []
  ? []
  : Arr extends [infer H]
  ? [...Result, MapPredicate<H>]
  : Arr extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
  ? Mapped<[...Tail], [...Result, MapPredicate<Head>]>
  : Readonly<Result>;

type MapPredicate<T> = T extends Fn ? ReturnType<T> : never

type Fn = () => any
const execute = <Thunk extends Fn, Thunks extends Thunk[]>(thunks: [...Thunks]) =>
  thunks.map<ReturnType<[...Thunks][number]>>((thunk) => thunk()) as Mapped<[...Thunks]>

const result = execute([() => 42, () => 'string']) // [number, string]
```

As you might have noticed, return types of both functions are different.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by the fact that if I change `type Fn = () => any` to `type Fn = () => unknown`, your code stops compiling.

Comment: `type Fn = () => any` is used to infer any function without arguments. In this case `any` should not bother you. As you might have noticed, all infered types are without `any`. `unknown` is more strict, it is not assignable to `ReturnType<[...Thunks][number]>`. In general, you can use more common type `(...args:any[])=>any` for function constraints